# mysql match value, find similar and sort, then order the sorted groups by orginal match value

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Can't seem to get this query right. Here's what I need to do.

Get by Age under 40, example return...

```
| NAME |--| AGE |
|------|--|-----|
| Amy  |  | 26  |
| John |  | 22  |
| Dan  |  | 30  |
```

Find Names that are like the names returned from above and sort alphabetically...

```
| NAME |--| AGE |
|------|--|-----|
| Aaron|  | 33  |
| Amy  |  | 26  |
| Jacob|  | 25  |
| John |  | 22  |
| Dan  |  | 30  |
```

Sort the alphabetical groups by original returned age values values...

```
| NAME |--| AGE |
|------|--|-----|
| Jacob|  | 25  |
| John |  | 22  |-->was youngest from first query so his group goes first
| Aaron|  | 33  |
| Amy  |  | 26  |
| Dan  |  | 30  |
```

Comment: What makes a name "like" another name?

Comment: What is your SQL statement so far?

Comment: @scott sanders Starting with same first letter in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should allow you to order the results by age then names that match the first letter of the person of that person.  The OTHER p1 CRITERIA should be replaced with whatever other criteria you are using to determine the first group:

```
SELECT p2.NAME, p2.AGE 
FROM PEOPLE p1
JOIN PEOPLE p2
ON substring(p1.NAME,1,1) = substring(p2.NAME,1,1)
WHERE p1.AGE < 40
AND OTHER p1 CRITERIA
ORDER BY p1.AGE, p2.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks a million. By adding a (select...) after the first from I'm able to be even more detailed in ordering.